# Meteor Template Not Rendering Content Inside HTML Elements

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

### What I'm trying to do

It seems so simple, but I'm trying to use Meteor's account system with Iron:Router to setup an admin system for a web app. The admin section is the only part of the app with accounts. The admin section is to be at `/admin` and has a login template, and a data template which should be displayed after the admin logs in.

### The code

**Base Routers**

```js
Router.route('/', {
    template: 'user' // Not shown; works fine
});
Router.route('/admin', {
    template: 'adminDataPage'
});
```

**Templates**

```html
<template name="adminLoginPage">
    <div class="cover-wrapper-outer page-admin login">
        <div class="cover-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="cover-container">
                <div class="cover">
                    <form class="admin-login-form">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger login-failure">
                            The username or password is incorrect.
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <input class="form-control password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <input class="form-control submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log in">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<template name="adminDataPage">
    <div class="container-fluid page-admin admin-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="scrolling-table">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Make</th>
                                <th>Model</th>
                                <th>Engine</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td>Year</td>
                            <td>Make</td>
                            <td>Model</td>
                            <td>Engine</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<template name="adminLoggingIn">
    Logging in...
</template>
```

(This is incomplete as of right now but it doesn't relate to the problem.)

### The issue

The content inside the `adminDataPage` template is never rendered, no matter what I do. However, anything that *is not* inside an HTML element *is* rendered. For example, this *would* render:

```html
<template name="adminDataPage">
    Hello world!
</template>
```

The `world` in the following *would not* render:

```html
<template name="adminDataPage">
    Hello <span>world</span>!
</template>
```

The same goes with the `adminLoggingIn` template. However, anything in the `adminLoginPage` template works without an issue.

In essence, the login box is displayed, the client-side Javascript (not shown) takes care of logging in the user, the user sees `Logging in...`, then the user sees nothing and nothing is shown in the browser's inspector (unless there is un-nested plain text in the `adminDataPage` template).

### What I've tried

**If currentUser**

```html
<template name="adminDataPage">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <div class="container-fluid page-admin admin-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="scrolling-table">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Year</th>
                                    <th>Make</th>
                                    <th>Model</th>
                                    <th>Engine</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <td>Year</td>
                                <td>Make</td>
                                <td>Model</td>
                                <td>Engine</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="cover-wrapper-outer page-admin login">
            <div class="cover-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="cover-container">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <form class="admin-login-form">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger login-failure">
                                The username or password is incorrect.
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                            <input class="form-control password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <input class="form-control submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log in">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

This will render the login page when not logged in, as expected. However, once logged in, nothing is rendered. I have also tried integrating `{{#if loggingIn}}` but to no avail.

**Iron:Router hooks**

```js
Router.route('/', {
    template: 'user'
});
Router.route('/admin', {
    template: 'adminDataPage'
});
var requireLogin = function() {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render('adminLoggingIn');
        } else {
            this.render('adminLoginPage');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'admin'});
```

This will render the login page if not logged in, as expected, but will not render any content inside HTML elements within the `adminLoggingIn` or `adminLoginPage` templates.

### Specifications

Meteor v1.1.0.3

Iron:Router v1.0.9

### Conclusion

I'm so very confused why Meteor (or Iron:Router) refuses to render certain content in certain contexts. Of course, if anybody has any ideas to help resolve this, please shoot; it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't think this will solve the issue, but I would give an explicit `name: 'admin'` to the "/admin" route, just to be sure that the `onBeforeAction` is applied correctly to the "admin" route. Even though [the iron router documentation](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes) states "the router will guess its name based on the path", it is not explicit on *how* it will guess it.

Comment: Good point, that would prevent some future ambiguity. But as you suspected, that did not fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I have also read in the meteor forums about [issues using `Meteor.user()`](https://forums.meteor.com/t/flow-router-and-rendering-other-template-when-user-is-signed-into-the-application/7371/2) in such a case, where the user object won't be set correctly yet, so it is usually best to use `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: I've tried that also, along with setting a helper variable and using a template `{{#if user_logged_in}}`. I've even tried scrapping `Meteor.user()` in the hook and changing it to a simple `if (true)` but the problem remains. Thanks again, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blaze.render()` appears to be at fault here. Using `Blaze.render(Template.adminDataPage, document.body)` in the console will not render anything but—just like in my problem—plaintext nested directly inside the body element. It will not nest any DOM elements beneath body.

To test, I created a DOM element `<div class="test"></div>`, nested it within the body of the page, and called `Blaze.render(Template.adminDataPage, $('.test')[0])` and it worked. It wasn't formatted correctly, but it worked.

Adding a layout template for Iron:Router to use fixes the issue, like so:

```html
<template name="adminPage">
    <div class="test">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
Router.route('/admin', {
    name: 'admin',
    template: 'adminDataPage',
    layoutTemplate: 'adminPage'
});
var requireLogin = function() {
    login_dep.depend();
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render('adminLoggingIn');
            console.log('Logging in page');
        } else {
            this.render('adminLoginPage');
            console.log('Login page');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
        console.log('Data page');
    }
};
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'admin'});
```

Also, nesting the `{{#if currentUser}}` inside another element works:

```html
<template name="adminPage">
    <div class="test">
        {{#if currentUser}}
            <div class="container-fluid page-admin admin-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="scrolling-table">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Year</th>
                                        <th>Make</th>
                                        <th>Model</th>
                                        <th>Engine</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>Year</td>
                                    <td>Make</td>
                                    <td>Model</td>
                                    <td>Engine</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{else}}
            <div class="cover-wrapper-outer page-admin login">
                <div class="cover-wrapper-inner">
                    <div class="cover-container">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <form class="admin-login-form">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger login-failure">
                                    The username or password is incorrect.
                                </div>
                                <input class="form-control username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
                                <input class="form-control password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                <input class="form-control submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log in">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
Router.route('/admin', {
    name: 'admin',
    template: 'adminPage'
});
```

I'm not sure why Blaze refuses to attach certain elements to the body element, but these are some workarounds.

### Edit

A better workaround I found is to add an element to which Blaze can prepend the template DOM. `Blaze.render(Template.adminDataPage, document.body, $('.render-fix')[0])` where a hidden element with the class of `render-fix` is placed in the DOM at the time of the initial render will work. In essence:

```html
<template name="adminPage">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <div>User logged in stuff</div>
    {{else}}
        <div>User not logged in stuff</div>
    {{/if}}
    <div class="render-fix" style="display: none"></div>
</template>
```

It appears to me that Blaze will not attach any templates to body after the initial render.